# Qual código tem um custo maior? (Bubblesort em C)

Tags: c, complexidade-de-algoritmo

```
void bubblesort(int *A, int n) {
    int i, aux;
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        if(A[i]>A[i+1]){
            aux = A[i];
            A[i] = A[i+1];
            A[i+1] = aux;
        }
    }
    if(n-1>1)
        bubblesort(A, n-1);
}
void bubblesortI(int *A, int n) {
    int i, aux, j; 
    int troca=0;                //1
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){       //Pìor C. = 2n          Melhor C. = 1;
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1; j++){  //Pior C. = n²+n-2      Melhor C. = 2n
            if(A[j]>A[j+1]){    //Pior C. = (n²+n)/2    Melhor C. = n-1
                aux = A[j];     //Pior C. = (n²+n)/2    Melhor C. = 0
                A[j] = A[j+1];  //Pior C. = (n²+n)/2    Melhor C. = 0
                A[j+1] = aux;   //Pior C. = (n²+n)/2    Melhor C. = 0
                troca =1;       //Pior C. = (n²+n)/2    Melhor C. = 0
            }
        }
        if(!troca)              //Pior C. = n-1         Melhor C. = 1;
            break;
    }
    //Pior caso: O(n²)  Melhor caso: O(n)
}
```

Estou estudando ordenação e complexidade e acabei fazendo o código do bubblesort recursivo e iterativo e queria definir a ordem deles, só que eu não consigo entender como calcular a complexidade de códigos recursivos.

Na frente do código iterativo está o custo de cada linha.

PS: se alguém tiver um dica de cálculo de custo e complexidade de algoritmos recursivos, ficarei feliz.

Comment: O recursivo inclui um custo de memória dinâmica que não está previsto nos seus cálculos. Enquanto que a versão iterativa tem memória `O(1)`, a sua versão recursiva gasta `O(n)` de memória. Também vale ressaltar que o custo de uma chamada de função não é da mesma unidade de grandeza que o custo de uma operação matemática, sendo normalmente mais pesado (bem mais)

Comment: Além disto não consigo imaginar como uma simples operação de atribuição pode ter um custo quadrático no pior caso e 0 no melhor. Deveria ser 1 em qualquer caso. O mesmo vale para uma comparação. Olhando simplificadamente. De qualquer forma medir complexidade não é medir velocidade. Velocidade envolve uma quantidade enorme de fatores, inclusive o momento que está sendo executado. Se quiser saber a velocidade de rodar ambos e verificar. Se mudar a condição em que está executando a velocidade pode mudar. Se quer saber a complexidade, se eu não perdi alguma coisa, é para ter a mesma complexidade.

Comment: @Maniero Acho que ele considera que no melhor caso aquele código não é executado (o que está certo, btw)

Comment: @Maniero como o LINQ disse no melhor caso aquela parte do código não é executada e por isso tem custo zero, já no pior caso aquele código é executado todas as vezes e por isso ele custa (n²+n)/2, já que vai atribuir 1 nele todas as vezes, da mesma forma no if.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não sei se estou certo, mas o custo do algoritmo recursivo é ele vezes a quantidade de vezes que ele é chamado, não é isso?

Comment: @HatusDaniel isso seria verdade se o custo fosse homogêneo. Eu posso ter um algoritmo de ordenação que faça `o(n log n)` leituras e `o(n log n)` trocas, porém ele ser menos eficiente que um algoritmo que faça `o(n^2)` leituras porém `o(n)` trocas. Se o custo da troca for maior que o custo da leitura, tipo muito maior, o segundo algoritmo é assintoticamente linear perante o primeiro, que é linearítmico. Portanto, sim, na análise de complexidade você precisa levar em consideração a heterogeneidade do custo das operações

Comment: @LINQ mas ele está analisando linha por linha e não o algoritmo como um todo. Não é assim que se mede complexidade, se mede de forma atômica. Se vai fazer a análise na linha tem que ser só no que é feito naquela linha. Se vai analisar o laço tem que ser feito nele todo e não nas suas linhas.

Comment: @Maniero acho que você não entendeu, o que calculo linha por linha é o custo total, é como se fosse o custo da linha vezes quantas vezes vou passar por ela, isso ajuda na hora de você fazer a função de custo, porque ai eu só preciso somar as linhas que eu preciso, por exemplo a função de custo de troca seria CT(n) = (custo da linha x) + (custo da linha y) e assim por diante. E ai tendo a função de custo de troca posso calcular a ordem de troca.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado entendi o que você diz, que tem a complexidade de troca e a complexidade da leitura/troca. Mas o algoritmo como um todo teria uma complexidade, não?

Comment: Pelo comentário direcionado a mim acho que você não entendeu como se calcula complexidade, pelo comentário direcionado ao JeffersonQuesado entendeu, mas está navegando pelas duas formas.

Comment: @Maniero desculpa cara, mas acredito que você não entendeu, a forma que uso para calcular a ordem de complexidade de um algoritmo é o seguinte: eu pego a função de custo, e após isso encontro a função que domina assintoticamente essa função, utilizando a maneira ensinando no livro do Ziviani e de vários outros autores e alguns videos que encontrei na internet, mas vi que tem algumas formas diferentes. Mas obrigado assim mesmo.

Comment: Eu prefiro usar a que todo mundo usa, não a que você decidiu usar. Mas você pode fazer como desejar. Ajudei no que eu podia.

Comment: @Maniero ok, desculpa se te estressei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso iterativo, você calculou corretamente.

Pelo que eu entendi nos comentários, você quer avaliar a complexidade assintótica dos seus algoritmos. A análise de complexidade assintótica lida somente com o algoritmo e não com os detalhes específicos da linguagem onde o algoritmo é implementado. Na verdade, se formos considerar tudo, teríamos que levar também em conta o sistema operacional, o hardware e mais *n* outros fatores que pesam no cálculo do custo do seu código.

Pra evitar essa fadiga, a análise assintótica lida somente com a quantidade de vezes que cada linha do código será executada, e ao final consideramos somente o fator de maior grau (no caso do *bubblesort* é o `n²`). Se quiser saber mais sobre isso, você pode pesquisar sobre a notação **Big-O** no Google.

É fácil calcular a complexidade assintótica de um algoritmo iterativo, mas no caso de algoritmos recursivos, você terá que deduzir qual vai ser a sua complexidade através de uma análise numérica. Considerando o seu algoritmo:

```
void bubblesort(int *A, int n) {
    1 int i, aux;
    2 for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    3     if(A[i]>A[i+1]){
    4       aux = A[i];
    5       A[i] = A[i+1];
    6       A[i+1] = aux;
    7   }
    8 }
    9 if(n-1>1)
   10     bubblesort(A, n-1);
}
```

- Em um primeiro olhar, já verificamos que a linha do laço `for` será chamada sempre `n-1` vezes. Consequentemente, todo o código que está dentro desse laço também estará sujeito a ser executado `n-1` vezes. Como não existe mais nenhum outro laço aninhado e nenhuma outra chamada de função ou interrupção de código que valha a pena levar em conta, a complexidade desse trecho do código (linhas 2 a 6) é **O(n)**.
- Já para a chamada recursiva, você vai precisar analisar a condição de parada em conjunto com a próxima chamada. Se decrementamos o `n` a cada vez que chamamos a função recursivamente, e se a condição de parada faz o programa terminar quando `n-1>1` (ou, reescrevendo, `n > 2`), então sabemos que a função será chamada `n - 2` vezes. Novamente, levaremos em consideração somente o `n`.
- No total, a complexidade do seu código é de **O(n²)**, levando em conta o laço de repetição e as chamadas recursivas.

Se formos analisar outro código:

```
int funcaoRecursiva(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + funcaoRecursiva(n/2);
}
```

A complexidade desse código é de **O(log n)**. Por quê? Porque a função pára quando `n <= 0`, e `n` é dividido por dois a cada chamada recursiva. Ou seja, a função segue o tempo de `f(n) = n/2`, que é um exemplo simples de função logarítmica na base 2.

Espero ter ajudado a esclarecer a sua dúvida.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação cara, não tinha identificada essa diferença das análises, tanto que me pediram para fazer análise assintótica em um código em uma prova e eu fiquei perdido, ainda bem que fiz o certo kkk. Muito obrigado.